# How to disable optimistic locking in Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Optimistic Locking annotation does not work.

```
@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.NONE)
public class TestEntity {
    ....
}
```

and `@Lock` annotation does not work either:

```
public interface TestRepository<TestEntity, Long> extends JpaRepository<Version, Long> {
    @Lock(LockModeType.NONE)
    TestEntity findByName(String name);
}
```

So, I try to call:

```
entityManager.refresh();
```

It works, but it's a workaround.

```
EntityManager em = sharedEntityManagerBean.getObject();
em.refresh(testEntity, LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC);
testRepository.save(testEntity);
```

Could you tell me why optimistic lock annotation does not work and what's the best way to update DB row(entity) with the latest data?

Comment: i assume this http://springinpractice.com/2013/09/14/optimistic-locking-with-spring-data-rest may help you somehow

Answer (score 5):

The `OptimisticLockType.NONE` disables the default optimistic locking mechanism for the `TestEntity`.

However, that would only be useful if you inherited the `@Version` property from a base class which is annotated with `@MappedSuperclass` or `@Inheritance`.

In your case, you could simply remove the `@Version` property if you don't want optimistic locking for this entity. However, that's usually a bad idea since it could lead to [lost updates](https://vladmihalcea.com/preventing-lost-updates-in-long-conversations/).

Maybe you want to use the [versionless optimistic locking](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-prevent-optimisticlockexception-using-hibernate-versionless-optimistic-locking/) which can lower the rate of conflicts generated by non-overlapping property chanages.

Again, the `@Lock(LockModeType.NONE)` is useless since it's implied by default. You can remove that as well. That's only meant for [acquiring an explicit logical or physical lock](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-java-persistence-locking/).

You are drawing the wrong conclusions thinking that optimistic locking is causing an issue which you didn't even describe.

Therefore, you need to formulate the question in a proper manner so that it's clear:

1. What is the actual problem that you are trying to solve?
2. Do you want optimistic locking or not?
3. Do you get a particular exception when doing the save?

Comment: I was remove @Version property, but entity lock mode is optimistic.   
---
1. problem is optimistic locking exception from multi requests.
2. not, I don't want to use application managed concurrency.
3. I uploaded test case in this situation. https://github.com/pilkyoon/optimisticlocking

Comment: With reference to your example with the MappedSuperclass annotation, I noticed that Hibernate prior to version 4.3.0.Final ignores OptimisticLockType configuration if the parent class has a Version annotated property.

Comment: Maybe it was a bug that got fixed.