# How to programmatically enable/disable optimistic locking in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, optimistic-locking

- java: 8
- spring-data-jpa: 2.0.7.RELEASE
- hibernate: 5.3.0.Final

We use feature flags (using [Togglz](https://www.togglz.org/)) in order to easily enable/disable features in our application without redeploying.

I've recently implemented optimistic locking for one of our tables, and I was wondering if I could apply this concept to optimistic locking. I do realize it's not a "feature" per se, but it's still a significant change.

Given that enabling optimistic locking in Spring Data JPA consists mostly of the `@Version` field and handling `ObjectOptimisticLockingFailureException`, in my opinion it wouldn't be too hard to enable/disable this programmatically and tell Spring not to auto-manage the `@Version` field, but I haven't found it documented anywhere.

In https://stackoverflow.com/a/42898080/1042273, it's hinted that I could use `@OptimisticLocking(type = OptimisticLockType.NONE)` as long as the `@Version` is in a `@MappedSuperclass`. So I thought I could have two similar subclasses, one with the annotation, another one without and switch between them according to the feature flag.

Would that work, or is there a better way to programmatically enable/disable optimistic locking?